# Plotting scatter plot where colour of point depends on category of data

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a list of data `X` which is an Nx2 matrix. I want to plot the first elements of each `X` against all the second elements of `X`.
First I have separated all the first and second elements of `X` into their own lists: `X_comp1`, `X_comp2`

I also have an Nx1 list of categories(cat), which shows which category the elements of X belong, i.e. if `cat[i] = 3`, it means that `X[i]` belongs in category 3.

I would like to use a different coloured point in the scatter plot for each category.

So far I only been able to achieve this through hard coding, but this will become very inefficient when there is more categories. 
Here's my code(it assumes there will be 5 categories):

```
#sample of X data
X = [[-0.13085379 -0.05958517],[ 0.02593188 -0.17576942],[-0.12505032 -0.02709171],[ 0.09790905 -0.18046944],[ 0.06437596 -0.20600157],[ 0.16287853 -0.2955353 ],[-0.52093842  0.33463338],[-0.03240038 -0.05431373],[-0.09645192 -0.14241157],[ 0.0807245  -0.26893815]]

X_comp1 = []#hold all the first components of X
X_comp2 = []#hold all the second components of X

cat = [1,3,2,1,5,3,2,4,4,1] 

#for testing just use 10 values, full file has over 3000 entries and 50 categories
for i in range(10):
    X_comp1.append(X[i][0])
    X_comp2.append(X[i][1])

for x1,x2,c in zip(X_comp1,X_comp2,cat):
    if c == 1:
        plt.scatter(x1,x2,c = 'b')
    elif c == 2:
        plt.scatter(x1,x2,c = 'g')
    elif c == 3:
        plt.scatter(x1,x2,c = 'r')
    elif c == 4:
        plt.scatter(x1,x2,c = 'c')
    elif c == 5:
        plt.scatter(x1,x2,c = 'm')
plt.legend([1,2,3,4,5])
plt.show()
```

I would like to make it more flexible to the number of categories, so that I don't have to end up writing loads of if statements for each category.

In order to achieve this I thought of having a list of colours:

```
colours = ["b", "g", "r", "c", "m",...]#number of colours depends on no. of categories
#This is the only element which I would like remain hard coded, as I want to choose the colours
```

Where each colour corresponds to a category. Then the program iterates through all the data and plots each point accordingly to the category. But I'm not sure how this could be implemented.

Comment: use dictionary `{1: 'b', 2: 'g', 3: 'r', 4: 'c', 5: 'm'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
color_dict = {1: 'b', 2: 'g', 3: 'r', 4: 'c', 5: 'm'}
for x1, x2, c in zip(X_comp1, X_comp2, cat):
    if c in color_dict:
        plt.scatter(x1, x2, c = color_dict[c])
plt.legend(list(color_dict.keys()))
plt.show()
```

Instead of checking for each value of `c` by using dictionary we can remove all the if statements

Answer (score 1):

For a pretty plot, you could also work with `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
sns.set()
df = pd.DataFrame({'X_1': X_comp1,'X_2':X_comp2, 'category':cat})
sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='X_1', y='X_2', hue='category')
```

If you care about which category should have what color, you can pass the `palette` parameter with your own category-color dict:

```
my_palette = {1: 'b', 2: 'g', 3: 'r', 4: 'c', 5: 'm'}
sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='X_1', y='X_2', hue='category', palette=my_palette)
```

There are also a bunch of predefined palettes if you're not satisfied with seaborn's default choice.